# Mimic Intellisense

Tags: c#, intellisense

I want to find C# in a string of c# code, with its parameters. Like in Visual C# as you type, in the intellisense you can find methods you've written inside the text area, I want to accomplish this basically. As the user is typing, and my intellisense pops up, I want to populate my intellisense with the new/edited methods that are in the textarea where the user is typing. Please suggest a good way to approach it, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Commercial: [Actipro SyntaxEditor - Windows Forms .NET Control](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/WindowsForms/SyntaxEditor/Default.aspx)

Free (quite basic): [DIY Intellisense](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/diy-intellisense.aspx)

Comment: No, I already built the intellisence and etc... I already know how to obtain methods and their parameters from dll/libraries. I need to know how to obtain methods and parameters from the text/string inside the textbox of my user.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) . it's an open source IDE for C# and VB.Net and it has intellisence.

Comment: I'm trying to use theirs, but its too difficult to implement. Maybe a pointer/heads up on how to implement?

Comment: Take a look at SharpDevelop\samples\CSharpCodeCompletion in the source code download.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is a C# parser - you can try to use Irony, a parser builder:

http://www.codeplex.com/irony

Or you can use F# with fslex and fslex:

http://stepheneasey.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/fslex-and-fsyacc-tutorial-parsing-sql/

These may not do exactly what you want but could at least get you in the right direction.